# How to resolve Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed error

Tags: ruby

I am trying to mock the data of node and run chefspec. But facing this error. Chefspec version=7.3.4 
Chef version=13.9.1
Is there any problem with the simulation? how do I resolve the handler error? 
Is there something I'm missing here? How can I debug the  Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout?

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'python_package[setuptools]'
================================================================================

Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of ["/usr/bin/python2.7", "-", "setuptools==40.5.0"] ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: No handlers could be found for logger "pip._internal.index"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 43, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 543, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for setuptools==40.5.0
---- End output of ["/usr/bin/python2.7", "-", "setuptools==40.5.0"] ----
Ran ["/usr/bin/python2.7", "-", "setuptools==40.5.0"] returned 1

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /chef-recipes/cookbooks/poise-python/files/halite_gem/poise_python/python_providers/base.rb

138:         python_package 'setuptools' do
139:           parent_python new_resource
140:           version setuptools_version if setuptools_version.is_a?(String)
141:         end
142:       end

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /chef-recipes/cookbooks/poise-python/files/halite_gem/poise_python/python_providers/base.rb:138:in `install_setuptools'

python_package("setuptools") do
  package_name "setuptools"
  action [:install]
  default_guard_interpreter :default
  declared_type :python_package
  cookbook_name :"poise-python"
  parent_python python_runtime[2]
  version "40.5.0"
  timeout 900
end

System Info:
------------
chef_version=13.9.1
platform=ubuntu
platform_version=16.04
ruby=ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-linux]
program_name=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/rspec
executable=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks
```